# mapping columns of table to model in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

Im new to entity framework. I was trying to map 2 columns of my table(`tblEnrollment`) to a model(`Enrollment`). Before that i had changed the name of `StudentId`column in `tblStudent` in the model `Student`.

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<Student> studentEntityConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<Student>();
studentEntityConfig.ToTable("tblStudent");
studentEntityConfig.Property(p => p.StuID).HasColumnName("StudentID");
studentEntityConfig.HasKey<int>(s => s.StuID);

EntityTypeConfiguration<Enrollment> enrollmentEntityConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>();
enrollmentEntityConfig.Map(map =>
{
    map.Properties(m => new
    {
        m.EnrollmentId,
        m.Grade
    });
});
enrollmentEntityConfig.ToTable("tblEnrollment");
```

Now when I'm trying to call a method to `GetAllStudents` from db I get the error

> "The property 'Grade' on type 'Enrollment' cannot be mapped because it has been explicitly excluded from the model".

However the props Grade and enrollment have no relation to that method. They are not even in the tblStudent.

Comment: Add the code for Student and Enrollment.

Comment: EF will do some implicit relationships, so if you have a EnrollmentId field in student or a navigation reference it could cause the issue. Really need to see those classes to help.